# z score vs z score of z scores

Tags: time-series, z-score

Suppose you have n time series, and you want to study the difference between the value of any pair of these time series. There seems to be two ways to go about this:

1. One way is to simply calculate the difference between the value of each pair of the times series, and look at the z score of the that difference.
2. The other way is, for each time series, calculate the z score that compares its current value with its historical value. Then for each pair of the time series, calculate the difference between their z scores and look at the z score of that difference.

Will the two method produce significantly different results?

Comment: Have you tried to check it yourself?

Comment: I am doing it empirically right now. Trying to do it theoretically seems a bit too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, you are trying to compare two distributions.  The answers to the following question will help you solve the problem quickly and in a theoretical manner: [Test to measure statistical significance of z-scores?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177806/test-to-measure-statistical-significance-of-z-scores)

Another option would be to perform a [one-way ANOVA](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc47.htm) of all $n$ data sets, assuming equal variance.  If the ANOVA identifies a significant difference in one or more groups, a [Tukey multiple comparison procedure](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook//prc/section4/prc471.htm) or [pairwise t test](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-August/056136.html) can be conducted to identify the time series of interest.